# Checkbox in Repeater control in asp.net is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox column in Repeater control, which is not maintaining the state even I have used binding only once when page is loaded for the first time. Every time it returns Checked=True, even I uncheck it. Here is the code.

This is .aspx code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCols" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptCols_ItemDataBound" >     
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <table width="200px" border="1" id="tblRpt" style="background-color:White;border-color:#CCCCCC;border-width:1px;border-style:None;font-family:Arial;font-size:X-Small;width:180px;border-collapse:collapse;">
          <tr>
             <th>COLUMN</th>
             <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
          </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
      <tr runat="server" id="tblRow">
         <td><asp:Label id="lblCol" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("Col1")%>'></asp:Label> </td>        
         <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkSelect" runat="server" Checked= '<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Col2")) %>'/></td>
         <td style="visibility:hidden"><asp:Label ID ="lblHidCol" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Col3") %>' /></td>
     </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
      </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is the aspx.cs code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            FillColsGrid(false); //Binding only once..
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblException.Text = ex.Message.ToString() ;
    }
}
```

And I want to get current state of the checkbox using this button event, which is not working, returning the same when page was loaded first time:

```
protected void wibHideShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<UserSettings> lstColsGrid = new List<UserSettings>();

    string sUser = Session["UserId"].ToString();
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptCols.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            UserSettings us = new UserSettings();
            Label lblColName = item.FindControl("lblCol") as Label;
            CheckBox chkSel = item.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox; //Here is the issue
            Label hidAppName = item.FindControl("lblHidCol") as Label;

            us.BemsId = sUser;
            us.ApplicationName = hidAppName.Text;
            us.ColumnName = lblColName.Text;
            us.ColumnValue = chkSel.Checked.ToString();
            us.LastUpdateDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            lstColsGrid.Add(us);
        }
    }
    rptCols.DataSource = LoadColsDataSet(lstColsGrid);
    rptCols.DataBind();

}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Removed my other answer because the problem then is elsewhere, and I suspect it might be because your repeater gets rebinded on postback. Try removing the Eval from your checkbox in the repeater, just to test, and see if you then can get the correct state from your checkboxes when you then check and uncheck. Instead of using Eval you can bind values in your OnItemDataBound in codebehind

Comment: I removed Eval and assigned values to each fields from rptCols_ItemDataBound event. The issue remain same. When I uncheck and do postback, that value is not reflecting in postback when I loop through each items in button click event.

Comment: Have you tried breaking and stepping in the postback/pageload and checking the values at that time for your repeater? You can also check Request.Form to see what is actually posted to the server - either via a browser tool or page_init/pageload.

Comment: Yes tried Request.Form as well, no luck.

Comment: And is the correct value actually send to the server in the form object?

Comment: When page is loaded for the first time, some checkboxes are checked (based on database value). If I uncheck any and submit the request,  Form.Request["AutoGeneratedChkBoxName"] is sending value of that checkbox as "on" instead of null. I have seen other behavior is the default checked value of checkbox is "on,on" instead of "on". Also the other hidden field value stored as "Val,Val" instead  of "Val".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how i solved this issue:

Here is the repeater in ASPX page:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height:140px" id="DivMainContent">  
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptCols" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCols_ItemDataBound"> 
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <table id="tblRpt" style="background-color:White;border-color:#CCCCCC;border-width:1px;border-style:None;font-family:Arial;font-size:X-Small;width:180px;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr class="GridHeader" style="height:15px;">
                <th>COLUMN</th>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" id="tblRow">
           <td><asp:Label id="lblCol" runat="server"></asp:Label> </td>
           <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkSelect" runat="server"/></td>
           <td style="display:none"><asp:Label ID ="lblHidCol" runat="server"/></td>
        </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</div>
<div id="DivFooterRow" style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">
     <input type="hidden" id="hidChk" runat="server" />
</div>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="wibHideShow" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="XX-Small" runat="server"
     ToolTip="Save Columns to Hide or Show" Text="Hide/Show" OnClick="wibHideShow_Click"  />
<br />
```

at the end of page, write this jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValues() {
    var str = $("#DivMainContent :input").serialize();
    $("#hidChk").val(str); //hidden field
}
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", showValues);
showValues();
```

ASPX.CS code

```
int iChk = 1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
             this.rptCols.DataSource = LoadColsDataSet(); //load data from database
             this.rptCols.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //display error in some label
    }
}
protected void rptCols_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            Label lblCol = e.Item.FindControl("lblCol") as Label;
            CheckBox chkCol = e.Item.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
            Label lblHidc = e.Item.FindControl("lblHidCol") as Label;

            lblCol.Text = drv.Row["DBCol1"].ToString();
            chkCol.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(drv.Row["DBCol2"].ToString());
            lblHidc.Text = drv.Row["DBCol3"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblException.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}

protected void wibHideShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<UserSettings> lstColsGrid = new List<UserSettings>();
    iChk = 0;
    string sUser = Session["BEMSID"].ToString();
    ArrayList ar = GetChecked();
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptCols.Items)
    {
        UserSettings us = new UserSettings();
        Label lblColName = item.FindControl("lblCol") as Label;
        Label hidAppName = item.FindControl("lblHidCol") as Label;

         us.BemsId = sUser;
         us.ApplicationName = hidAppName.Text;
         us.ColumnName = lblColName.Text;
         us.ColumnValue = ar[iChk].ToString();
         us.LastUpdateDate = System.DateTime.Now;
         iChk++;
         lstColsGrid.Add(us);
     }
     rptCols.DataSource = LoadColsDataSet(lstColsGrid); //Update and load data
     rptCols.DataBind();
     iChk = 1;
 }

    private ArrayList GetChecked()
    {
        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
        int chkNo = 0;
        string strChkNo = string.Empty;
        string[] strChk = hidChk.Value.Split('&');

        //initialize array with all false
        for (int i = 0; i < rptCols.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ar.Add("false");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < strChk.Length; i++)
        {
            strChkNo = strChk[i].Replace("%3A", ":");
            if (strChkNo != "")
            {
                chkNo = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Match(strChkNo, @"\d+").Value); //Extract int from string
                ar[--chkNo] = "true";
            }
        }

        return ar;
    }
```