# Checkboxes in grid or repeater in asp.net not sending updated checked status to server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

What could be the reason of aspx page is not sending checkbox's checked status back to the server. I am getting weird status of checkbox like "on, on" instead of just "on" or "null" using Request.Form. Also findcontrol method is giving correct status due to this issue.

Comment: Can you demonstrate or explain your issue more clearly.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Yes, for this issue, code is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883346/checkbox-in-repeater-control-in-asp-net-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment40546531_25883346

Comment: uh... is this a question in relation to another currently unanswered question?

Comment: Yes Kritner.. I am still struggling..

Comment: Yes but - in that question, you have answered it yourself and marked that as the correct answer. So is it the correct answer, or not ?

Comment: Yes, I got solution that way and posted the answer, so that other can take benefit of it..